# Using docx python library, how to apply color and font size simultaneously

Tags: python, fonts, colors, font-size, python-docx

I am writing to an .docx file using python docx library. I want to prespecify the font size and color of a paricular sentence. My problem is that I am not able to do it simultaneously. Let me illustrate -

```
from docx import Document        
from docx.shared import Pt       #Helps to specify font size
from docx.shared import RGBColor #Helps to specify font Color
document=Document()              #Instantiation
p=document.add_heading(level=0)
p.add_run('I want this sentence colored red with fontsize=22').font.size=Pt(22)  #Specifies fontsize 22
p.add_run('This line gets colored red').font.color.rgb=RGBColor(255,0,0)    #Specifies RED color
document.save('path/file.docx')
```

Result: [image]

I am very well aware that I am setting the color `Red` to the second sentence, and since there is an `=` before `Pt(22)` and `RGBColor(255,00)` so I cannot apply `fontsize` and `color` simultaneously

Is there a way to apply both attributes simultaneously?

Editted: I want the line `I want this sentence colored red with fontsize=22` in Red color.

Comment: What would you gain by doing the two simultaneously?

Comment: Well, my intent is to have the line 'I want this sentence colored red with fontsize=22' colored Red. End result is important, means are not, so some other method is equally good if you have a one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe you can make this

```
document=Document()
p=document.add_heading(level=0)
wp = p.add_run('I want this sentence colored red with fontsize=22')
wp.font.size = Pt(22)
wp.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Very clean solution. Thank you so much and a good job given that today was your first day with stackoverflow. Many thanks!