# How can I change letters’ color?

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to write letters in docx.I wrote codes,

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()

document.add_heading("TITLE", 1)

document.save("test.docx")
```

But when I run the codes, the letter of TITLE is colored blue.I want to add color black to TITLE.I searched the way of it in docx document, but I cannot find it.How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of:

[Write text in particular font color in MS word using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979095/write-text-in-particular-font-color-in-ms-word-using-python-docx)

[Using docx python library, how to apply color and font size simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689438/using-docx-python-library-how-to-apply-color-and-font-size-simultaneously)

You would need to use the font property.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()

run = document.add_heading().add_run("TITLE")

font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)

document.save("test.docx")
```

Please see the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/font-color.html) documentation.